# How to create drill down table in excel using Closed Xml excel dll in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, openxml, closedxml

[image]

Here Gross Margin is parent.
 Below rows are child so i want to
have drill down at parent level i.e at Gross margin

Is there any way to do this using closedxml excel or do i need to use something else?

Comment: If you mean the outline / grouping feature, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783647/2610249) for how to do it with ClosedXML.

Comment: i mean expanding and collapsing of parent row.

Comment: ohk Sir !!!! Here Gross Margin is the parent (see above image) and the rows below that are its child segments. So when i do export to excel, be default + sign should come at Gross Margin, when i will click on Gross margin then it should display child segment.

Comment: @Raidri Yes Thank You!!! But how would i make rows collapsed by default i have used "    ws.Rows(4, 5).Group();
            ws.CollapseRows(2); not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
ws.Rows(firstChildRowNumber, lastChildRowNumber).Group();
ws.CollapseRows(1); // collapse to level 1
```

Comment: can i drill down particular range instead of rows ?

Comment: No, only complete rows or columns can be grouped.