# ClosedXML and C#: How to collapse rows by Default?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am trying to write code which produces excel report with pivot table. For accomplishing this task I am using ClosedXML library. The output looks like this:
[image: ClosedXML produced excel worksheet with pivot table]

The problem is that I have to get all groups of data collapsed by default, i.e. in the output I should see the following:
[image: Desired output - every row is collapsed.]

In other words, my output should contain collapsed rows and only summary should be displayed. How can I achieve this in code? Which method should I use?

```
        pt.ShowRowStripes = true;
        secondWorksheet.FirstRow().Hide();
        secondWorksheet.TabActive = true;
        secondWorksheet.CollapseRows(1);
        secondWorksheet.Rows().Collapse();
        pt.EnableShowDetails = false;
        pt.ShowValuesRow = false;
        secondWorksheet.PageSetup.ShowGridlines = true;
        secondWorksheet.ShowGridLines = true;
        workbook.PageOptions.ShowGridlines = true;
        secondWorksheet.PivotTables.First().EnableShowDetails = false;
```

Comment: The command `secondWorksheet.CollapseRows(1);` should work and collapse all rows in the groups. Not sure if there are conflicts when working with pivot tables. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783647/2610249) for another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by ClosedXML. Pivot tables are still very much work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Using ClosedXML.Signed version 0.94.2, this worked for me:

```
IXLPivotTable pivotTable = workbook.Worksheet("SheetContainingPivotTable").PivotTables.First();
pivotTable.ColumnLabels.ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetCollapsed(true));
pivotTable.RowLabels.ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetCollapsed(true));
```